# Defining Dates at the Top of Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a lot of hardcoded dates in my data, rather than go in and manually change all of them, I was hoping to just be able to define a "Start date" and "End Date" at the top of my code. Sort of like MACROS in SAS, but in Oracle SQL

I've tried to use the DEFINE function at the top of my code, but am getting errors when actually executing

```
DEFINE start_Date = '01-SEP-2019';
DEFINE end_date = '30-SEP-2019';

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE LAST_PAID_DATE >= &start_date
  AND LAST_PAID_DATE <= &end_date
```

I am expecting those dates just to make my code work as it would if i would type them in manually. Instead, I am getting this error:

ORA-00904: "SEP": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

The way I defined it is how it is stored in the table that I am referencing but it's telling me it is invalid when I do this

Any help?

Comment: Maybe you need to use to_date, either when defining the variable or when using it.

Comment: Do you programs have multiple steps?  Or are they just a single query like in your example?

Comment: [Date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) require the `date` keyword, e.g. `define start_date = date '2019-09-01'` However, `define` is not part of SQL and is only provided in certain applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just one query, you can use a CTE (common table expression):

```
WITH PARAMS AS (
      SELECT DATE '2019-09-01' as start_date , DATE '2019-09-30' as end_date
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM PARAMS CROSS JOIN
     TABLE_NAME
WHERE LAST_PAID_DATE >= PARAMS.start_date AND
      LAST_PAID_DATE <= PARAMS.end_date;
```

Comment: I know  frustrated programmers frequently get Chronic traumatic encephalopathy (CTE) from hitting their head with the palm of their hand. But perhaps you can spell outt what CTE stands for in this context?

Comment: @Tom . . . I added what the acronym stands for, although I'm not so certain that that helps very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sqlpus, then put '' around your variable names.  In addition to be safe put to_date function too

```
To_date('&start', 'yyyymmdd')
```

Now when it prompts give date in the format